# Selah ~ Does it mean 'forever' 'certainly' 'basket' 'pause', 'yahoo', a kabbalistic meditative device, or none of the above?

Tags: tefilla, parshanut-torah-comment, words, tehilim-psalms

Does anyone know a Jewish interpretation of "selah" in the psalms? Literally it seems to mean something about basket or hanging, but I don't know how this works into psalms.

Jewish sites say it may mean "forever", or "certainly" or even that it is a non-sense word like "Yahoo" or "Yeehah". Non-Jewish sites have it meaning musical direction. Thanks to anyone with insights or answers.

Rabbi Aryeh Kaplan, z'tl, made a case for the psalms being primarily meditative exercises. Could Selah be some sort of Kabbalistic device?

Comment: The way hebrew works btw, a word can both mean forever and basket. Assuming that there is a cultural connection between what a basket does and the concept of forever.  Sort of like the word "shefa"

Comment: Oh thank you! I was reading last night, after asking this question, Rabbi Aryeh mentioned David HaMelech's song referring to himself "My heart is hollow within me" (Tehilim 109:22) and indicated this meant that David had made himself a vessel for the Divine. The footnote to this statement is the Tanya, Avodah Zara 4 b, Likutey Amarim 1:1. So, thanks for validating that "basket" and "forever" could be connected in this way!

Comment: Where/in which of Rabbi Kaplan’s books does he mention this?

Answer (score 7):

*Rada"k* ([on ch. 3](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14255&st=&pgnum=12)) is of the opinion that it is a term of elevation, in this case indicating elevation of the voice in reciting the word/line/psalm in which it appears. The word appears only in *T'hilim* and *Chavakuk*, which are both poetic. (He cites as a proof text *Y'sha'yahu* [62:10](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95_%D7%A1%D7%91_%D7%99), in which the same root refers to clearing a path.)

Alternatively, *M'tzudas Tziyun* says it *always* means "always", which is in line with "the *targum*", and Malbim says it is *always* an indication of a pause (*[ibid.](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Tehillim/3.2#e0n6)*).